# Is there a alternative to ArCore for AR development in Android?

Tags: android

I am trying to build an app using ArCore. When I run the app on my device it says that latest version of ArCore is required. When I click continue it takes me to Google Play Store for downloading latest version of ArCore but it informs me that my device is not compatible this version. My device is Xiaomi Redmi 4X.

I have tried other AR apps from play store and they work fine e.g. Inkhunter. My question is that if my device is not capable of running ArCore then how I am able to use Inkhunter. Is there any other alternative to ArCore that I can use for AR development in Android.

Comment: Inkhunter uses lines drawn on the arm to create the effect so, I would categorize it as "Indicia" based AR. ARCore needs no lines on your table or floor and is officially limited to [supported devices](https://developers.google.com/ar/discover/supported-devices). As of now your question is too broad as there are a variety of solutions depending on what you are trying to do and any answers may be opinion based.

Comment: We used to use Vuforia before ARCore became sufficiently feature rich on it's own.  Vuforia can work even on non-ARCore devices but will delegate to ARCore (or ARKit) if it's running on a device where those feature are available.  Wikitude is another one.